# Night out after a doctor's appointment

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, story

> A South African and an American walked out of the doctor's office after having their chests radiographed. Since everything was fine, they decided to celebrate with glasses of Scotch in a nearby bar. They watched the football game and bet on which team would end up being the winner. They laughed at the players' shirts, thinking they were ridiculous. They danced with women and had a lovely time. Eventually, a friend came to pick them up in his old Ford. They laughed and quoted Shakespeare in the back seat. This fun-filled evening took place in, umm...

Where exactly?

Comment: My gut says there are three possible locations but I have yet to connect all the dots. Should I post it as a partial answer or wait till I find the link?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This fun-filled evening took place in ...

> ... **Quebec**.

The story ...

> ... mentions synonyms of Nato phonetic alphabet codewords from Z to Q in reverse alphabetical order:
>
>  A **Zulu** and a **Yankee** walked out of the doctor's office after having their chests **X-rayed**. Since everything was fine, they decided to celebrate with glasses of **Whiskey** in a nearby bar. They watched the football game and bet on which team would end up being the **Victor**. They laughed at the players' **Uniforms**, thinking they were ridiculous. They danced **Tango** with women and had a lovely time. Eventually, a friend came to pick them up in his old Ford **Sierra**. They laughed and quoted **Romeo** in the back seat. This fun-filled evening took place in **Quebec**.

Comment: Does this come with practice? Being able to identify the pattern so exactly!

Comment: @nikki: Yes, perhaps. The Nato code is a bit of a staple for puzzles, together with chemical symbols, postal abbreviations of US states and, unfortunately, Pokémons. Jafe, who makes some good and approachable puzzles, has used the technique of hiding patterns in stories before, so I started looking for one. Once you have found the pattern, everything falls into place, which is nice.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: So we can try to find something *other* than these to make it more challenging?